# Tomcat 7.0.29 servlet-api classloader issue

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, classloader

I'm currently trying to change our build from a manual process (MyEclipse / export as war) to an automatic Maven Build.

The war application built by MyEclipse deploys and works just fine on our Tomcat 7.0.29 installation (Windows 7).  In the MyEclipse build path, we have configured a user library (tomcat), which contains all jars from `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`.

We have some servlet listeners and filters that use javax.servlet.http.* classes (HttpSessionEvent etc).  They are packaged under `WEB-INF\classes\com\mycompany\filters`

When deploying the war built by Maven I get `NoClassDefFoundError` on the `HttpSessionEvent` class.  I did a trace with -verbose:class JVM option and I saw that the last class loaded is my filter from the 
`c:\apache\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\mycompany\filters` directory.  I then tries to load / find HttpSessionEvent and is unable to do so.

The `servlet-api.jar` is of course in my `$CATALINA_HOME\lib` directory.

In my pom.xml I have this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.29</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have no other servlet-api.jar files anywhere in my path / classpath (doublechecked the lib/ext and endorsed directories of my jdk and jre as well)

My maven dependency:tree looks like this :

```
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.rpc:jaxrpc-impl:jar:1.1.3_01:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.rpc:jaxrpc-spi:jar:1.1.3_01:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.0.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.faces:javax.faces-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.1.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-api:jar:4.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-ui:jar:4.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-api:jar:4.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar:7.0.29:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-email:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] \- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.170:test
```

I've been searching on this for a while on the internet, and from what I've read this must have something to do with the tomcat classloader.  Very probably there's something wrong with the packaging of my war.  However, I haven't found a solution yet.

Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: I would probably clone the project and remove everything but a single servlet or filter and try if it works. And/or try to deploy it to a different engine, Jetty for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `WEB-INF/lib` of the built .war to be absolutely sure `servlet-api.jar` is not there? The Maven dependency has the right scope as long as I can tell.

Your `build` section in the pom.xml should be similar to this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>war_name</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And no, don't put `servlet-api.jar` in your web app's `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
Also, I don't think you need the tomcat user library. The only libraries you need are `JRE System Library xx` and Maven `Dependencies`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, absolutely, the built war does not contain the servlet-api.war.  And indeed, the servlet-api.jar should not be put in the WEB-INF/lib directory, it will be ignored in any case by tomcat.  My version of the war plugin is 2.1.1, I'll check to see if version 2.2 fixes this (which would seem strange)

Comment: Any relevant difference between the .war built by MyEclipse and the one built by Maven? (by the way have you run a `mvn clean` recently?)

Comment: Yes, the war built by MyEclipse contains more jars, like apache commons stuff, lucene etc... I might be missing some jars in my maven build, but given the fact that the project already compiles there won't be many of them.  BTW, I have already tried to delete all jars from the exploded WEB-INF/lib directory, copy all the jars from the MyEclipse war and redeploy.  That does not work either (NoClassDefFoundError on HttpSessionEvent as well).

Comment: oh and one more thing, if I replace the classes of the Filters / Listeners by the ones generated/compiled by MyEclipse, I no longer get a NoClassDefFoundError on HttpSessionEvent, but a NoClassDefFoundError on Logger (which is a log4j logger, which is also in the WEB-INF/lib).  Strange.

Answer (score 0):

[Classloading in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) this will help you in understanding.

Place your jar in **/WEB-INF/lib**

> Application Classloader — A class loader is created for each web application that is
>   deployed in a single Tomcat instance. All unpacked classes and
>   resources in the /WEB-INF/classes directory of your web application,
>   plus classes and resources in JAR files under the /WEB-INF/lib
>   directory of your web application, are made visible to this web
>   application, but not to other ones.

Comment: Thanks, what I understand from that link is that my webapp gets a "Webapp" classloader (which will load classes from WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib/*.jar).  The class loader inherits from the "Common" classloader, which should be able to load the HttpSessionEvent class just fine.  Or does my webapp classloader not delegate to the parent classloader when it doesn't find a class (that would make no sense at all)?

Comment: `$CATALINA_HOME\**libs**` seems incorrect it should be `$CATALINA_HOME\lib` directory name is invalid in the question? Is it a mistake or really jars are placed in libs directory? In that case Common classloader will not be able to find class.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (typo), $CATALINE_HOME = C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.29 and it's in directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\lib